# html tags + ascii names and numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Our users want to be able to type in

```
&lt;p&gt;some text goes here.</p>
```

which gets saved to the database and then outputs to the screen as it should, i.e. however the browser renders `<p>` tags without actually displaying the `<p>` tags.

At the same time without affecting the existing database generated pages where the user has been typing in

```
<p>some text goes here.</p>
```

Is this possible?

An example of "the customer is always right".  Do I have a choice?  No, it's something they want for some reason which is beyond me.

Comment: If you want the browser to display exactly what the user entered with no translation/rendering, then you'll have to do `echo htmlspecialchars($the_users_inputs)` in your output function(s).

Comment: are you looking for something that WYSIWYG editor does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish. If you WANT the browser to render the tags when you display them, then use can use `html_entity_decode`:

```
echo html_entity_decode( "&lt;p&gt;some text goes here.</p> ");
echo html_entity_decode( "<p>some text goes here.</p> ");
```

If not, then you can pass the strings to `htmlspecialchars`

```
echo htmlspecialchars( "&lt;p&gt;some text goes here.</p> ");
echo htmlspecialchars( "<p>some text goes here.</p> ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `htmlspecialchars()`. It will escape any HTML characters out for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at examples of `htmlentities` and `strip_tags`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

You can store the date at which your choice of encoding changes in the code, and then you can use the timestamp for each entry in the database (I assume you have a 'created'/'modified'/'timestamp' or similar field?) to decide which behaviour should be used when outputting the content.

Alternatively you could write a script to update the old entries in the database to the new format (e.g. calling `htmlspecialchars()` or `html_entity_decode()` on each of them).